# IBM Db2 on Cloud script creating tables in the wrong schema

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

On IBM Db2 on Cloud I have imported a script.  I created a new schema under which I want to have the new tables created, but when I run the script, it keeps trying to create the tables in a previous schema.  Not sure how to get the scripts to create the tables in the new schema.

I have tried the below script without the .SQL_GROUPING_SORTING and it tries to add the tables to a different schema.  I have changed the default schema in the Run SQL window within db2 to SQL_GROUPING_SORTING and am now getting the error

> ""KZF72118" does not have the privilege to perform operation "IMPLICIT CREATE SCHEMA".. SQLCODE=-552, SQLSTATE=42502, DRIVER=4.26.14"

DDL statement for table 'HR' database:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES.SQL_GROUPING_SORTING (
                            EMP_ID CHAR(9) NOT NULL, 
                            F_NAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
                            L_NAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
                            SSN CHAR(9),
                            B_DATE DATE,
                            SEX CHAR,
                            ADDRESS VARCHAR(30),
                            JOB_ID CHAR(9),
                            SALARY DECIMAL(10,2),
                            MANAGER_ID CHAR(9),
                            DEP_ID CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
                            PRIMARY KEY (EMP_ID));
                            
  CREATE TABLE JOB_HISTORY.SQL_GROUPING_SORTING (
                            EMPL_ID CHAR(9) NOT NULL, 
                            START_DATE DATE,
                            JOBS_ID CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
                            DEPT_ID CHAR(9),
                            PRIMARY KEY (EMPL_ID,JOBS_ID));
 
 CREATE TABLE JOBS.SQL_GROUPING_SORTING (
                            JOB_IDENT CHAR(9) NOT NULL, 
                            JOB_TITLE VARCHAR(15) ,
                            MIN_SALARY DECIMAL(10,2),
                            MAX_SALARY DECIMAL(10,2),
                            PRIMARY KEY (JOB_IDENT));

CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENTS.SQL_GROUPING_SORTING (
                            DEPT_ID_DEP CHAR(9) NOT NULL, 
                            DEP_NAME VARCHAR(15) ,
                            MANAGER_ID CHAR(9),
                            LOC_ID CHAR(9),
                            PRIMARY KEY (DEPT_ID_DEP));

CREATE TABLE LOCATIONS.SQL_GROUPING_SORTING (
                            LOCT_ID CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
                            DEP_ID_LOC CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
                            PRIMARY KEY (LOCT_ID,DEP_ID_LOC));
```

Comment: Share the script or the CREATE TABLE statement

Answer (score 1):

With the Db2 on Cloud [Lite Plan](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Db2onCloud?topic=Db2onCloud-free_plan)

> The Lite plan uses one database schema.

So the only schema you can use is the one that matches your user name. In your case this would be `KZF72118`

Create your tables with out a schema name, and they will be created in schema `KZF72118`.

You would need to use one of the other plans to remove this restriction

Comment: Thank you.  The "Lite" version only allows 1 schema.